# AS3: Merge multiple 2d Arrays - indexOf not working

Tags: actionscript-3, multidimensional-array, merge, indexof

I want to merge multiple 2dim Arrays which are of the type [unique number][a fix number]
Since I would like to merge them (and have unique results) I'm searching inside the "retArr" if array[unique number] is present.

```
Array1: retArr
Array2: arg  (multiple 2dim Arrays)

// before here is an additional "for each"-loop which gives me in every iteration a "new" arg-Array.
for (var p:uint = 0; p<arg.length; p++){
  if(retArr.length ==0){
    var tmp:Array = new Array();
    tmp.push(arg[p][0]);
    tmp.push(arg[p][1]);
    retArr.push(tmp);
  }
  else{
    for(var i:uint = 0; i<retArr.length; i++){
      if (retArr[i].indexOf(arg[p][0]) == -1){
         var tmp:Array = new Array();
         tmp.push(arg[p][0]);
         tmp.push(arg[p][1]);
         retArr.push(tmp);
         break;
      }
    }
   }
}
```

I think the line

```
if (retArr[i].indexOf(arg[p][0]) == -1)
```

is my Problem, since I'm getting double-results in my retArr.
Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize: You have an array of arrays and each array in the parent array has two elements. You want to filter out all the arrays that have duplicated values at index 0. Is this correct?

If so the problem is in your second for loop. Say this is what you have in arg:

```
var arg:Array = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
```

On your first iteration, retArr contains nothing, so [0, 1] is added and the second for loop doesn't run

On your second iteration, the second for loop executes once because the first element of [2, 3] does not appear in [0, 1]

Now here's the problem: On your third iteration, the second for loop executes. It checks to see if [0, 1] contains 2. It doesn't, so it adds it to retArr. It never even checks to see if [2, 3] contains 2.

What you need to do is loop through all elements of retArr, and if there were no matches at all, then you can safely add the array.

```
var matchFound:Boolean = false;
for(var i:uint = 0; i<retArr.length; i++){
  if (retArr[i].indexOf(arg[p][0]) != -1){
     matchFound = true;
     break;
  }
}
if( ! matchFound) {
  var tmp:Array = new Array();
  tmp.push(arg[p][0]);
  tmp.push(arg[p][1]);
  retArr.push(tmp);
}
```

There is another problem: You are filtering out an array even if it's element 0 matches another array's element 1. To only filter out array's that have duplicate element 0's, change this

```
if (retArr[i].indexOf(arg[p][0]) != -1){
```

to this

```
if (retArr[i].indexOf(arg[p][0]) == 0){
```

It would probably be faster and less complicated if you just did this:

```
if(retArr[i][0] == arg[p][0]){
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this should be possible by using splice or concat
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#concat%28%29

you can just attach arrays to `retArr`, without calculating the length and iterating